# Mongoose callback does not execute

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to execute a callback after calling `.findByIdAndDelete`. Which actually **does** delete my item in the mongodb database, but the callback does not execute.

I've tried several solutions from other posts, but to no avail. How can I fix this?

Here's my code:

**Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BoardSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
}, { collection: 'boards' });

module.exports = Board = mongoose.model('board', BoardSchema);
```

**Method Call**

```
router.delete('/delete-board', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body); // This does print out

        var id = req.body.id;

        Board.findByIdAndDelete(id, (err, board) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            console.log('stupid'); // This doesn't print out
            
            return res.send({
                message: 'Board has been deleted',
                board: board
            });
        });

})
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? As you have a check for 'err', it should throw an error if any error occurs. So, because of that, your console is not executing

Comment: @Dinesh No error what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `req.body,id` is valid id of any element in your database. If it isn't valid, your program won't execute callback, because it'll be not able to delete any element.

Comment: I know the ID is valid because the item got deleted from my database.